# API changes for Australian PayPal site? Or just ExpressCheckout in General?

Tags: php, api, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a script that submits payments to PayPal via form using BusinessID and Token.  Apparently it still works for PayPal in U.S., but a client of mine in Australia said they were told by PayPal that this method no longer works. In reading documentation, I see that now a BusinessID, Password and Signature may be required.  What has changed in the API using the IPN process and what steps does my client need to set up in their account to make this work.  Any help is appreciated to adapt my code to new standards.

---

### My old form:

```
     <? if ($test == "1"){ ?>
    <form name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <?} else {?>
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" name="_xclick" id="_xclick">                                          
    <? } ?>
   <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
   <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?=$businessid;?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?=$SITE_URL;?>/notify_payment.php?tx=   <?=$test;?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?=$SITE_URL;?>/thankyou.php?px=<?=base64_encode($bid);?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?=$SITE_URL;?>/buybidsunsuccess.php">
   <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD" />
   <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?=$bidpackname;?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?=$amt;?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?=$bid."_".$uid;?>" >
```

---

### And my IPN Page:

```
    $header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

if ($test =="1") {
    $fp = fsockopen ('www.sandbox.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
                      } 
    else 
                     {    
     $fp = fsockopen ('www.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
                      }
    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    // custom varible
    $invoice_id = $_POST['invoice_id'];
    //retrieve payment status
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $customvar = $_POST["custom"];

    if (!$fp) {
    // HTTP ERROR
    } else {
    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
    $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
```

Comment: i have always found the paypal forums extremely good for answering questions about paypal

Comment: First post on Stack Overflow.. I was in the PayPal forum, and thought my question was being posted there.

Answer (score 0):

What token do you speak of?  I see no token in your old form other than your own BID, which PayPal does not care about. I'm not aware of anything different about Australia for such an integration -- it ought to work for any PayPal business account that can receive payments (and is not set to block unencrypted payments)

Express Checkout is something fairly different implementation-wise, though the end result is a very similar customer experience.  It is a superior integration, and I recommend EC if you have the knowledge to write API calls (which will authenticate using the business account's API username, API password, and API signature).  A further benefit of using EC is that your server communicates synchronously with PayPal, so there is no need for an asynchronous IPN message to programmatically confirm the payment took place.